# Lowercase Dictionary Keys in Swift

Tags: swift

I need to convert a `Dictionary` with mixed case keys in the same exact `Dictionary` but with only lowercase keys.

Here is my attempt (It works but I found this implementation extremely rough)

```
extension Dictionary {
    func lowercaseKeys()->Dictionary<String, AnyObject>{
        var newDictionary = Dictionary<String,AnyObject>()

        for k in keys{
            if let k_string = k as? String{
                newDictionary[k_string.lowercaseString] = self[k] as? AnyObject
            }
        }
        return newDictionary
    }
}
```

Can you suggest a more elegant way to solve this problem?

Comment: I suggest you moving this question to http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Did you mean "generic values" instead of "generic keys"?

Comment: @Cosyn probably the "generic" adjective is not the right word :/ I wanted to say that keys might be lowercase, uppercase or both... I've updated the question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Changes its own keys without the need of a temporary dictionary ;)

```
var dict = ["HEJ":"DÅ", "NeJ":"tack"]

for key in dict.keys {
    dict[key.lowercaseString] = dict.removeValueForKey(key)
}

print(dict)
```

> [hej: DÅ, nej: tack]

## EDIT

I made this extension, its a little dirty for now but I will update it again.

```
extension Dictionary {
    mutating func lowercaseKeys() {
        for key in self.keys {
            let str = (key as! String).lowercaseString
            self[str as! Key] = self.removeValueForKey(key)
        }
    }
}

var dict = ["HeJ":"Då", "nEJ":"taCK!"]
dict.lowercaseKeys()
print(dict)
```

> ["hej": "Då", "nej": "taCK!"]

## EDIT 2

```
extension Dictionary where Key: StringLiteralConvertible {
    mutating func lowercaseKeys() {
        for key in self.keys {
            self[String(key).lowercaseString as! Key] = self.removeValueForKey(key)
        }
    }
}

var dict = ["NamE":"David", "LAST_NAME":"Göransson"]

dict.lowercaseKeys() // Will compile

var dict2 = [0:"David", 0:"Göransson"]

dict2.lowercaseKeys() // Won't compile because Key isn't StringLiteralConvertible
```

Comment: great, that's really... neat!

Comment: This solution doesn't even compile.  Xcode says "Cannot invoke initializer for type 'String' with and argument list of type '(Key)'".  I'm guessing new versions of swift disallow this.

Comment: @daredevil1234 you could try to fix it and edit ;) I dont have time right now

Answer (score 3):

Smth like that?

```
  var dict = ["KEY": "value"]
  var newDict = [String: AnyObject]()

  for (key, value) in dict {
     newDict[key.lowercaseString] = value
  }
```

Comment: This doesn't work if the original dictionary keys are heterogenous. OP said the keys were "generic", I interpret that as "heterogenous": keys can have another type than String.

Comment: Does "lowercase " have any meaning for data types other than `String`?

Comment: @MatterGoal is it appropriate solution for you?

Comment: @katleta3000 is a solution really similar to the one I've implemented. I think that Arbitur solution is the most elegant.

Answer (score 2):

Arbitur's answer, updated for Swift 3:

```
extension Dictionary where Key: ExpressibleByStringLiteral {
    public mutating func lowercaseKeys() {
        for key in self.keys {
            self[String(describing: key).lowercased() as! Key] = self.removeValue(forKey: key)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution, no force casting, totally safe.

```
protocol LowercaseConvertible {
    var lowercaseString: Self { get }
}

extension String: LowercaseConvertible {}

extension Dictionary where Key: LowercaseConvertible {
    func lowercaseKeys() -> Dictionary {
        var newDictionary = Dictionary()

        for k in keys {
            newDictionary[k.lowercaseString] = self[k]
        }
        return newDictionary
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Just as an alternative to looping, you could use the `map` function:

```
func lowercaseKeys () -> Dictionary<String, AnyObject> {
    var newDictionary = Dictionary<String,AnyObject>()
    Array(keys).map { key in
        newDictionary[(key as! String).lowercaseString] = self[key] as? AnyObject
    }
    return newDictionary
}
```